# Heat conduction or radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics

In an automotive "radiator", with the fan blowing air through it, what is the primary means of heat transfer.  And the 2nd and 3rd means.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Have you done any research?

Comment: I think that with the air being blown through it, that the primary heat transfer is conduction.  The next would be radiation, least is convection.  I say conduction 1st because the air molecules are actually bombarding the radiator surface.

Comment: Why do you think that would imply conduction?

Comment: I don't know, my thoughts are starting to sound dumb now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mechanism of convection heat transfer in car radiator operation is not exactly what you are alluding to in your comment to @Ole Krarup.  You are alluding what we call "natural convection," which is the result of density gradients in a gas.  But, a much more important heat transfer mechanism, dominant in a car radiator operation, is "forced convection."  This is where we force the fluid to flow, and this works to hugely enhance the rate of heat transfer.  The forced convection is present both within the air forced to blow across the radiator tubes as well as in the coolant flowing through the radiator tubes.

There is a very close relationship between convection and conduction.  Convection is constantly bringing fresh fluid from regions away from the heat transfer surface into the region in close proximity to the heat transfer surface.  This causes the temperature gradients in the fluid immediately adjacent to the heat transfer surface to be much higher than if forced convection were not occurring.  These much higher temperature gradients result in much higher conductive heat transfer rates across the "thermal boundary layers" adjacent to the surfaces.  The heat transfer rates are greatly enhanced.

The blowing of air across the finned heat transfer tubes of the radiator, and the turbulent flow of coolant within the radiator tubes reduce the thermal boundary layer thickness substantially in the air outside the tubes and the coolant flowing inside the tubes.  This is called convective heat transfer, but it is really a combination of convection and enhanced conduction (within the fluids).  There is also pure conduction resistance through the metal walls of the tubing and the cooling fins, but these conductances are very high and can be neglected compared to the resistances imposed by the air- and coolant thermal boundary layers.

Radiation heat transfer is also present, but to a much lesser extent.

Comment: If the radiator was bare aluminum, but now it is coated with a very thin black color, thin to minimize any insulating effect, would it aid the heat transfer?  Since the radiant cooling is minimum and convection is the main factor I'm thinking that the black color will not change the efficiency very much. ?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.  The effect would be negligible.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is "convection". The air immediately surrounding the engine is heated up and quickly transported away by the fan. It pushes the hot air away and replaces it with new, cold air. This is then heated up and the cycle continues.

Whether conduction or radiation take the second place will depend on the temperature of the engine. For very high temperatures, radiation will definitely overshadow both convection and conduction as the radiated power increases as $T^4$.

Comment: Looks like homework to me. Do not do other's homework for them.

Comment: I thought for convection you need convection currents (heat rising).  Or is any air movement around the heat source considered convection?

Comment: Ole Krarup, first off, I'm asking about the heat from the radiator, not directly off the engine.  Without the liquid coolant in the motor circulating through the motor then through the radiator with the fan, it would severely overheat.  What precisely would be happening around the radiator for conduction to factor in?  I'm now thinking that where the radiator directly touches another part of the car is the only conduction?